# how i put condition to sure that values of outputs in FindRoot?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

i want to put condition in this like x>0,0<y<1

```
FindRoot[{Exp[x - 2] == y, y^2 == x,x > 0 && 0 < y < 1}, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}]
```

but it dosen't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSolve[{Exp[x - 2] == y, y^2 == x, x > 0, 0 < y < 1}, {x, y}]
```

> `{{x -> 0.019026, y -> 0.137935}}`

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

When using [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) it is often useful to plot the equation(s) to find initial estimates to use to localize a particular root.

```
ContourPlot[{Exp[x - 2] == y, y^2 == x}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 2},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.3, 0.75}]]
```

[image]

With `FindRoot` the initial estimates will select a root

```
FindRoot[{Exp[x - 2] == y, y^2 == x}, {{x, #}, {y, #}}] & /@ {0.1, 2}

(* {{x -> 0.019026, y -> 0.137935}, {x -> 2.44754, y -> 1.56446}} *)
```

Comparing with [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

```
NSolve[{Exp[x - 2] == y, y^2 == x}, {x, y}, Reals]

(* {{x -> 0.019026, y -> 0.137935}, {x -> 2.44754, y -> 1.56446}} *)
```

With `NSolve`, specifying constraints will select the root

```
NSolve[{Exp[x - 2] == y, y^2 == x, #}, {x, y}] & /@ {y < 1, y > 1}

(* {{{x -> 0.019026, y -> 0.137935}}, {{x -> 2.44754, y -> 1.56446}}} *)
```